# Vista window appears at the top and cannot be deleted

Tags: windows-vista

I have no idea how he did it but on my dad's laptop, which is running Vista, there is a window at the top; you can only drag it down but not remove, minimize or maximize it as those options do not appear. I restarted but it's still there.

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:
[image: strange window]

How do I remove it? It used to be my laptop but I've never seen that when I used it.

Comment: This kind of question belongs on Super User, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Super User? I'm looking to 20 articles related to this one about vista so why would this not belong on stack overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a deskband.  You can move it around with the little grippy thing on the left.  You should be able to right click the Taskbar, select toolbars, and uncheck whichever one is that one.

Comment: I cannot move it around, only drag it down. I also unchecked all toolbars and it's still there

Comment: Can you run spy++ and get the window name?

Comment: is it something I need to download or is allready in vista? if I need to download could you provide a link please?

Comment: It's part of Visual Studio / Windows SDK tools.  You really need to move this to SuperUser.com.

Comment: ah ok thanks, I didn't know what mmyers meant with super user :)